# Is there a two-variable prime-representing polynomial (in the sense of Jones-Sato-Wada-Wiens)?

Tags: diophantine-equations, nt.number-theory, lo.logic, prime-numbers

In the math.se question [Proof of no prime-representing polynomial in 2 variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/59846/1778), Alon Amit asks if Ribenboim's claim that a prime-representing polynomial (a Diophantine polynomial in which the positive values are precisely the primes) must have at least three variables has been proven.  Alon suggested that perhaps the number was a typo, that all that is known is that (trivially) no univariate polynomial is prime-representing.

As of Jones 1982 [1, p. 550] the question of the existence of a universal Diophantine equation in two variables was open, so certainly it was not known that the number of variables for the special case of the primes was more than 2 at that time.

[1] James P. Jones, "Universal Diophantine equation", *The Journal of Symbolic Logic* **47**:3 (1982), pp. 549-571.

Answer (score 10):

Davis [1] writes that the two-variable case of universal Diophantine equations is still open as of 2006.  (Ribenboim's book was published in 1996.)  So the question of a prime-representing polynomial in two variables was (and, presumably, is) still open.

[1] Martin Davis, [[FOM] Decidability of Diophantine equations](http://cs.nyu.edu/pipermail/fom/2006-December/011184.html), post to the FOM mailing list, December 14 2006.

Answer (score 0):

Greckuk, Grechuk, & Wilcox [1] give an algorithm for solving all 2-variable 3-monomial Diophantine equations. Two-variable Diophantine equations with 4 or more monomials are still open as of 2023.

[1] Bogdan Grechuk, Tetiana Grechuk, Ashleigh Wilcox, [Diophantine equations with three monomials](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022314X23001336), Journal of Number Theory
Volume 253, December 2023, Pages 69-108.